# How to compile and run a C++ program from Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, execute

I am trying to write, compile and execute a "HelloWorld" C++ program using Eclipse. I have managed to install and run Eclipse, create a new project and write the HelloWorld program. Now I would like to compile it and to run.

I did not find "Compile" option in Eclipse, but I found "Build Project" option in the "Project" menu. I assume that Build is what I call "compilation". After I clicked this options, Eclipse generated "Debug" folder, containing "src" sub-folder as well as 3 files: "sources.mk", "objects.mk" and "makefile". First, I do not know what these files mean (and which of them is my "executable"). Second, I still need to execute my program. I tried to click "Run" option in the "Run" menu. As a result I got an error message: "Launch failed. Binary not found".

Can anybody, please, help me to compile and run my code using Eclipse.

Comment: search Eclipse tutorial online?

Comment: there is no C++ support for a vanilla version of Eclipse, refer to the plugin that you are using for this, probably you are using CDT so refer to the CDT docs.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Comment: Just a hint that will greatly increase your knowledge: try to answer at least one question for every question you ask...

Comment: Try Codeblocks much sexier.

Comment: @sonicboom Please keep comments productive.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse being an IDE is meant to create projects not restricted to just one file as a result  multiple files exists  which have to be linked and compiled so as to work in sync as per the methods implemented in the project.To run the project or a particular program a binary of that particular project is required  which gets created only if the build is successful .So a successful build is must for binary creation which in turn is responsible for running the project or program.

So first build the project using Ctrl+B after succesfull build then run the project.

Answer (score 1):

This simple question was asked nine years ago, so I don't know if it is still active. Anyway, one thing not mentioned in the responses so far that might be helpful to others is that Eclipse requires a "Run Configuration" to run programs. From the original post, if the "Build Project" command returned successfully, then the "Debug" folder should also contain a file called "HelloWorld" at the same folder level as "makefile" and "objects.mk". That is your executable. To run it, go to Run -> Run Configurations, which should produce a popup containing a field called "C/C++ Application". Click the "Browse" button, find, and select the "HelloWorld"  executable in the "Debug" folder. Click "Run" in the lower right and you should see your output.